# sed print line with nth occurrence of regex

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed, range

lets say we have the following data

```
 B346879 length: 12 B34 L677
 B111879 length: 32 B33 L677
 B545879 length: 34 B34 L677
 B344879 length: 98 B33 L677
 B090879 length: 45 B33 L677
```

i'm looking for 'B34' so from this series I would want to print the 1st and 3rd line.
But if I would use:

```
cat t.txt | sed -n '/B34/p' | awk '{print $1", "$4" "$5}' | sed 's/B//g'
```

The 4th line would also be printed because 'B34' matches the first 3 chars of 'B344879. I know that with something like `sed 's/pattern/replacement/n'` you can replace only the nth occurance of a regex. But how does it works with printing. I tried stuff like `sed -n '/B34/2p'` but that's invalid.

Comment: Why don't you just search for `\ B34\ ` (with spaces)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn 's/^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+\s+){2}(B34)\s+(\S+)/\1, \3 \4/;T;s/B//g;p' file
```

Answer (score 1):

try this line:

```
awk '$4=="B34"' file
```

your rest commands (sed, cat...) could be merged into the above one-liner:

```
awk '$4=="B34"{gsub(/B/,"");print $1,$4,$5}' file
```

test it with your example:

```
kent$  echo " B346879 length: 12 B34 L677
 B111879 length: 32 B33 L677
 B545879 length: 34 B34 L677
 B344879 length: 98 B33 L677
 B090879 length: 45 B33 L677"|awk '$4=="B34"{gsub(/B/,"");print $1,$4,$5}' 
346879 34 L677
545879 34 L677
```

**EDIT**

awk takes the space as `FS`, so it doesn't matter how long your 3rd field is, for example:

```
kent$  echo " B346879 length: 17777777777777777772 B34 L677                                                                                                                 
 B111879 length: 32 B33 L677
 B545879 length: 34 B34 L677
 B344879 length: 98 B33 L677
 B090879 length: 45 B33 L677"|awk '$4=="B34"{gsub(/B/,"");print $1,$4,$5}' 
346879 34 L677
545879 34 L677
```

**EDIT**

ok, see what you mean, so this should work:

```
awk -F'length:[ 0-9]*' '$2~/^B34/{sub(/B/,"",$1);sub(/B/,"",$2);print $1,$2}'
```

see test: the first line is in special case.

```
kent$  echo " B346879 length:212 B34 L677
 B111879 length: 32 B33 L677
 B545879 length: 34 B34 L677
 B344879 length: 98 B33 L677
 B090879 length: 45 B33 L677"|awk -F'length:[ 0-9]*' '$2~/^B34/{sub(/B/,"",$1);sub(/B/,"",$2);print $1,$2}'
 346879  34 L677
 545879  34 L677
```

Comment: The reason for not going for that solution is that sometimes the 'length number' in the 3rd column is sometimes 3 digits long which makes the data look like f.ex.:   B348769 length:113 B33 L677
 B093279 length:145 B33 L677. Then 'B34' moves to $3 so I would have to go for smthng like '$3=="B34" || $4=="B34"'. But I was hoping for a sed one-liner

Comment: @user2682171 I don't get what did you mean `Then B34 moves to $3`. even if your 3rd column is 100 digits long, it is till 3rd field. and the next field is 4th, which is Bxx.  did you try my awk one-liner with your data?

Comment: no, that number 'grows' expands into the other direction, so it will form a single string with 'length:'. Making B34 the 3rd column. Like so: B348769 length:113 B33 L677

Comment: @user2682171 ok I see, but still can be done in one-liner. see 2nd **EDIT** and I think `$3=="B34" || $4=="B34"` isn't bad either..

Answer (score 1):

```
cat t.txt | awk '$4 == "B34" {print $1", "$4" "$5}'|sed s/B//g
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the word boundary notation `\< ..\>` here.

```
cat t.txt | sed -n '/\<B34\>/p' | awk '{print $1", "$4" "$5}' | sed 's/B//g'
```

Output

```
346879, 34 L677
545879, 34 L677
```

Print the matching lines.

```
sed -n '/\<B34\>/p' t.txt
```

Output

```
B346879 length: 12 B34 L677
B545879 length: 34 B34 L677
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but sed -n '/\bB34\b/p' t.txt doesn't seem to work?

Comment: still no luck.. I found that \b...\b are word notations. But for some reason neither \<...\> nor \b...\b prints anything.